# Removing transisiton effect from widget addition in Pyqt

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, qt5

In my application, I have developed various UI files using Qt Designer to handle different functionalities such as login and data view. To manage these pages effectively, I created separate classes for each UI file and incorporated them into a stacked widget for display within the main application.

However, I have encountered an issue where, upon adding a widget to the stacked widget, an undesirable transition effect occurs. This effect disrupts the intended user experience, and I am keen on removing it entirely. Instead, I aim to establish a static page change when adding a widget to the stacked widget, ensuring a seamless transition for the user.

Despite my efforts, I have been unable to identify a suitable solution to achieve this desired behavior. As a result, I am seeking assistance from individuals knowledgeable in PyQt. If anyone with expertise in PyQt can provide guidance or suggestions to help me resolve this issue, I would greatly appreciate it.

In summary, my objective is to eliminate the disruptive transition effect that occurs when adding widgets to the stacked widget, and instead, establish a smooth and static page change. I am hopeful that someone with expertise in PyQt can offer valuable insights to overcome this challenge.

adding a small snippet

```
widget.show()
widget.addWidget(new)
widget.resize(800, 600)
app.exec_()
```

in a fucntion I am trying to add a new widget as follows:

```
logger.info("Job List launched")
new = JobList(token)
new.resize(self.width(), self.height())
new.show()
widget.addWidget(new)
widget.setCurrentIndex(widget.currentIndex() + 1)
```

Comment: Don't show the widget before adding it to QStackedWidget, just add it and call `setCurrentWidget(new)`.